Unexpected behavior with "only" restriction type in owlready2
I don't understand the reasoning for model below in owlready2:
class Equipment(Thing): pass

class Task(Thing): pass
class EquipmentTask(Task): pass

class task_executed_by_equipment(EquipmentTask >> Equipment, FunctionalProperty): pass
class task_included_subtasks(Task >> Task): pass

class EquipmentTask(Task): equivalent_to = [task_executed_by_equipment.exactly(1, Equipment)]
class MainTask(EquipmentTask): equivalent_to = [task_included_subtasks.only(EquipmentTask)]

task = Task(task_executed_by_equipment=Equipment())
sync_reasoner()

The reasoner output says:
* Owlready * Equivalenting: owl.Thing t.Task
* Owlready * Equivalenting: t.Task owl.Thing
* Owlready * Reparenting t.task1: {t.Task} => {t.EquipmentTask}
* Owlready * Reparenting t.equipment1: {t.Equipment} => {t.Task, t.Equipment}

An equipment individual should not be classified as task.
If I change the "only" type to "some" then it looks as I expected.
Someone a hint/idea about the reasoning that is followed?
Or where my line of thought goes wrong?
Thanks in advance, Patrick.
Edited:
The same phenomenon is occurring in following simplified example:
class P(ObjectProperty): domain=[C]
class C(Thing): equivalent_to = [P.only(C)]

This results in A equivalent to Thing according to HermiT.
(The ELK reasonor in Protege does not come to this inference)
Another example that might help to get things sharper (from presentation of Alan Rector et.al.)
Intuitive definition:
Class MargheritaPizza 
    subclass from Pizza
    restriction(hasTopping someValuesFrom(TomatoTopping))    
    restriction(hasTopping someValuesFrom(MozzarellaTopping)) 

But problem: missing restriction that toppings must only be tomato or mozzarella
Correct:
Class MargheritaPizza 
    subclass from Pizza 
    restriction(hasTopping someValuesFrom(TomatoTopping))
    restriction(hasTopping someValuesFrom(MozzarellaTopping))
    restriction(hasTopping allValuesFrom(TomatoTopping or MozzarellaTopping)))

Actually this looks rather intuitive. And also in line with comment from @Ignacio to have a companion someValuesFrom restriction.
But when the "allValuesForm" term is replaced by "only" like in OWLready (from Manchester OWL?), then just having the restriction(hasTopping only(...)) sounds fully intuitive again.
What would be the meaning for this "allValues" restriction only, in the light of this Pizza example?

This happens because Task is equivalent to owl:Thing in your model. That means any individual becomes an instance of Task as any individual indeed is an instance of owl:Thing

and Task is equivalent to owl:Thing because of the following axioms: 1) task_included_subtasks Domain: Task 2) MainTask SubClassOf: EquipmentTask 3) EquipmentTask SubClassOf: Task 4) MainTask EquivalentTo: task_included_subtasks only EquipmentTask

I probably don't get the effect of the "only" properly.  Why does this result in Task becoming same as Thing?

step 1: 1) task_included_subtasks Domain: Task
2/3) MainTask SubClassOf: Task
4) MainTask EquivalentTo: task_included_subtasks only EquipmentTask

step 2: 1*) task_included_subtasks some Thing SubClassOf: Task
2/3) MainTask SubClassOf: Task
4) MainTask EquivalentTo: task_included_subtasks only EquipmentTask

step 3: 1*) task_included_subtasks some Thing SubClassOf: Task
2/3) MainTask SubClassOf: Task
4*) task_included_subtasks only EquipmentTask SubClassOf: MainTask

step 4: 1*) task_included_subtasks some Thing SubClassOf: Task
2/3) MainTask SubClassOf: Task
4**) task_included_subtasks only owl:Nothing SubClassOf: MainTask

step 5: 1*) task_included_subtasks some Thing SubClassOf: Task
2/3/4**) task_included_subtasks only owl:Nothing SubClassOf: Task

so in the end everything is becoming an instance of Task

Thanks for the extensive reply. I did not completely understand the logic behind the steps. But it triggered me further towards a more simple problem.

Class C equivalent to property P only A, where P domain is A, results in A = Thing
(The ELK reasonor in Protege does not come to this inference by the way. Only HermiT)

@UninformedUser these comments are very complete, you should put them in an answer.

Short version: using a forall (only) restriction on a property without an existential (some) restriction has the effect of making the class expression equivalent to top, because it applies to all individuals whether or not they have the property. Making MainTask equivalent to that expression might be the issue, did you mean equivalent or subclass?

See my comment above about simplified case. When I remove A from P domain, then the problem does not occur, which sounds opposite to your statement "whether or not they have the property". All in all, for me a quite unintuitive construct.

In my previous comments I mixed up class name. A should be C.
See the problem statement where I now added the simplified version.
